# Meaning of ECMAScript notation syntax?

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I am confused with how to properly read [this syntax line](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-names-and-keywords).

- Why `IdentifierName` is defined with an `IdentifierName`?
- Why do you have a **new line** in the middle of the definition?

How to read this notation?

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> IdentifierName ::
>        IdentifierStart
>        IdentifierName IdentifierPart
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a recursive definition, which is not uncommon in grammar notations.

`IdentifierName` is composed of `IdentifierStart` or `IdentifierName IdentifierPart`. If we expand `IdentifierName` in the second alternative again we get

```
IdentifierStart IdentifierPart
IdentifierName IdentifierPart IdentifierPart
```

and so on.

To express this in an informal way: `IdentifierName` is compose of `IdentifierStart` followed by an arbitrary number of `IdentifierPart`s.

---

From the [specifiction itself](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-grammar-notation):

> As another example, the syntactic definition:
>
> ```
> ArgumentList:
>   AssignmentExpression
>   ArgumentList,AssignmentExpression
> ```
>
> states that an `ArgumentList` may represent either a single `AssignmentExpression` or an `ArgumentList`, followed by a comma, followed by an `AssignmentExpression`. This definition of `ArgumentList` is recursive, that is, it is defined in terms of itself. The result is that an `ArgumentList` may contain any positive number of arguments, separated by commas, where each argument expression is an `AssignmentExpression`. Such recursive definitions of nonterminals are common.

Comment: You mean we get IdentifierStart **IdentifierStart** IdentifierName IdentifierPart IdentifierPart, right?

Comment: No. I probably didn't write it clear enough: `IdentifierName IdentifierPart` expands either to `IdentifierStart IdentifierPart` (`IdentifierName -> IdentifierStart`) or to `IdentifierName IdentifierPart IdentifierPart` (`IdentifierName -> IdentifierName IdentifierPart`).